# Python: Is there a way to randomly select an element that has an h3 tag in selenium chromedriver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to create a bot that randomly selects elements and generally browses around looks 'human'.
I want to simply select any element that has an h3 tag at random, but I only seem to be able to select specific id strings for the bot to find and click on, but I haven't seen anyone just select something by just an h3 tag. Is this even possible?

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3") should return all the h3 tag elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all h3 elements with driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3") in a list and use the random module's 'sample' method to get one of them at random.